# Slow queries on indexed columns (large datasets)

Tags: mysql, index, performance, innodb

I've got some large MySQL (5.5.60) tables where queries take 60 seconds+ to complete.

product_base (1.5GB, 26 million rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `product_base` (
  `EAN13` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `company_tk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `EAN13` (`EAN13`),
  KEY `company_tk` (`company_tk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

attribute (11.8GB, 126 million rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute` (
  `EAN13` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_t` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_n` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_d` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `EAN13` (`EAN13`),
  KEY `attribute_type` (`attribute_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

attribute_type (16KB, 59 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute_type` (
  `attribute_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_name` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_type` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seq` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `html` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `attribute_type` (`attribute_type`),
  KEY `seq` (`seq`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Example slow query:

```
Query_time: 61.629684  Lock_time: 0.000138 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 28141979
select p.EAN13, p.company_tk, a.attribute_type, a.val_t, t.title, t.field_name from product_base p
inner join attribute a on p.EAN13=a.EAN13 
inner join attribute_type t on a.attribute_type=t.attribute_type 
where p.EAN13=705632109762 and (a.attribute_type=1 or a.attribute_type=3)
order by t.seq;
```

Running `explain` on that query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys        | key            | key_len | ref                      | rows    | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | range | attribute_type       | attribute_type | 5       | NULL                     |       2 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref   | EAN13,attribute_type | attribute_type | 5       | eandata.t.attribute_type | 6299937 | Using where                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref   | EAN13                | EAN13          | 54      | eandata.a.EAN13          |       1 |                             |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

Server/OS:
Debian 8 64bit | 24GB RAM (MySQL is using 70% of this) | 60GB SSD | 2xIntel Xeon CPU E5506 @ 2.13GHz | MySQL 5.5.60

[Innodb settings here](https://pastebin.com/ABD06tCt)

MySQL my.cnf

```
# * Fine Tuning
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 20
table_cache            = 9552
thread_cache = 10
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 16M
query_cache_size = 512M
join_buffer_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 15G
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
#innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8

max_heap_table_size = 2G
tmp_table_size = 2G
wait_timeout = 120
interactive_timeout = 120
```

Any suggestions for the slow queries?

Comment: `select STRAIGHT_JOIN p.EAN13, p.company_tk, ...`.  How does that perform, by comparison?

Comment: That's better - 12s vs 60s. BUT - I stripped the query back to `SELECT EAN13 from product_base WHERE EAN13=xxxxxxxx` and it was still slow. That all changed when I put quotes around the EAN13 value, now it works fine :/

Comment: Ha, oops, yes... integers are not strings, except when they are.  MySQL has an easier time coercing a string expression to match an integer column than doing it the other way around.

Comment: The joins should not use the EAN - if you add an int as key to the base table, the attributes can join using this, not the EAN. Int comparisons are a LOT faster.

Comment: Have you tried an composite index like: `CREATE INDEX index_name ON attribute (EAN, attribute_type)`?

Comment: No PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE or FOREIGN KEY constraints?

Comment: it is taking time on attribute table as per your explain output, it is examining 6299937 rows..


have you considered archiving some of your data ? this will definitely improve performance of your database instead of allowing tables to store millions of row.

Comment: How many rows in the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here. The other answers have some great optimisation tips, but the key to getting my queries down from 60s to 100ms was to treat the EAN13 field as a string in the where statement.

As an example:
`where p.EAN13=705632109762` became `where p.EAN13='705632109762'`

Comment: This is because `VARCHAR = int-constant` does not optimize well.  Either change the column to be `BIGINT` or add quotes around the constant (to make it a string).

Answer (score 1):

I would try using UNION except for OR condition.
You could try:

```
( select p.EAN13, p.company_tk, a.attribute_type, a.val_t, t.title, t.field_name, t.seq from product_base p
inner join attribute a on p.EAN13=a.EAN13 
inner join attribute_type t on a.attribute_type=t.attribute_type 
where p.EAN13=705632109762 and a.attribute_type=1 )
union all
( select p.EAN13, p.company_tk, a.attribute_type, a.val_t, t.title, t.field_name, t.seq from product_base p
inner join attribute a on p.EAN13=a.EAN13 
inner join attribute_type t on a.attribute_type=t.attribute_type 
where p.EAN13=705632109762 and a.attribute_type=3 )
order by 7;
```

Maybe MySQL optimizer will choose better execution plan.

Comment: As originally written, the `ORDER BY` is attached to the second `SELECT`.  I added parentheses so that the it will apply to the `UNION`.

Comment: Let's see the `EXPLAIN` to see if it changed.

Answer (score 1):

- You do InnoDB a disservice by not providing an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  Look at the data to see if an existing column or combination of columns is unique.
- Perhaps `EAN13` could be the PK of `product_base`?
- Perhaps `(EAN13, attribute_type)` could be the PK for `attribute`?
- In one table `modified` is a string type, in another it is `DATETIME`.  ??  Anyway, do you use the column?  If not removing it would make the table smaller, thereby possibly leading to a faster query.
- As already noted, the type inconsistency of `EAN13` led to a serious inefficiency.  This is because VARCHAR = int-constant does not optimize well. Either change the column to be `BIGINT` (if appropriate) or add quotes around the constant (to make it a string).
- These 3 tables smell like an "Entity-Attribute-Value" schema, which can usually be implemented with fewer tables -- hence more efficiently.  Is it EAV?
- You "can't tune your way out of a performance problem".  But if you also provided `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` after being up at least a day, I will review the `VARIABLES` you already provided.
- These are dangerously high; don't make them more than 1% of RAM:  `max_heap_table_size = 2G` and `tmp_table_size = 2G`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the ways to optimize let me to transform Your query to cartesian form (all joins are inner one, so it's correct) by replacing JOINs with commas and moving ON conditions to WHERE section:

```
SELECT p.EAN13, p.company_tk, a.attribute_type, a.val_t, t.title, t.field_name
FROM product_base p, attribute a, attribute_type t
WHERE p.EAN13=705632109762 
  AND p.EAN13=a.EAN13 
  AND a.attribute_type IN (1,3)
  AND a.attribute_type=t.attribute_type 
ORDER BY t.seq
```

Do You see? No conditional join of product_base needed, the condition `p.EAN13=a.EAN13` can be replaced with constant one `a.EAN13=705632109762`. And we obtain:

```
SELECT p.EAN13, p.company_tk, a.attribute_type, a.val_t, t.title, t.field_name
FROM product_base p, attribute a, attribute_type t
WHERE p.EAN13=705632109762 
  AND a.EAN13=705632109762
  AND a.attribute_type IN (1,3)
  AND a.attribute_type=t.attribute_type 
ORDER BY t.seq
```

There is the only condition on `product_base` table, and `EAN13` is already indexed, so nothing on that table can be optimised.

There is 2 conditions on `attribute` table. To optimize, You need to create composite index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_EAN_at ON attribute (EAN13, attribute_type)
```

If nevertheless the `attribute (attribute_type)` index will be used, add `IGNORE INDEX` hint. Moreover, check if You really needs it, maybe it can be deleted without consequences. And creation of `attribute (EAN13, attribute_type)` index makes the `attribute (EAN13)` index unnecessary.

There is only one joining condition plus ordering on `attribute_type` table. But this table is small, so I think no optimization needed, existent indices are sufficient for optimization.

Comment: Please use `JOIN..ON` syntax, not the antique comma-join.  The query plan will be identical, as you can see by `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: @RickJames While using JOIN syntax, the binding and filtering conditions are divided into several parts. While using comma-separated table list all the conditions are grouped into one group. So the ways to optimization are more visible. After finding ways to optimize we can rewrite the query back to JOIN syntax. But I think that is not nesessary in explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section

```
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
```

SHOULD NEVER BE larger than

```
innodb_log_file_size=5M
```

takes special handling to correct with 5.5  and after you get to 5.6 you may

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 to conserve CPU seconds every SECOND.
```

because you have innodb_buffer_pool_instances at 8.

Good luck.

For additional assistance, check my profile, clk Network Profile for contact info.